# pine scrip logic confusion

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

confessed in pine script logic
hi im trying to convert pine script to mql4 , my question is

what is this statement mean "x-x[length]" , x[length] is the the 14th element of the array x but what is x , i suppose it is the whole array but this make no sense there is no comparison between one element and whole array any

```
 help will be appreciated thanks

//@version=2
study("Pseudo Polynomial Channel",overlay=true)
length = input(14),morph = input(0.9,minval=0,maxval=1),mult = input(1.),flatten = input(1.)
//----
x = n
y = close
m(a,b) =>
    p = morph * a + (1-morph) * b
k = nz(m(k[length],y),y) + (x-x[length])/(x[length*2]-x[length]) * (nz(m(k[length*2],y),y) - nz(m(k[length],y),y))/flatten
k1 = sma(k,length)
er = cum(abs(y-k1))/n * mult
//----
a = k1 + er
b = k1 - er
//----
A = plot(a,color=#2196f3,linewidth=2,transp=0)
plot(k1,color=#e65100,linewidth=2,transp=0)
B = plot(b,color=#ff1100,linewidth=2,transp=0)
fill(A,B,#2196f3,transp=95)
```

Answer (score 0):

`x` is the equivalent of `x[0]`, so the most recent element of the time series. Note that Pine uses time series—not arrays—which entails the elements referred to with the `[ ]` history-referencing operator vary on each bar. See the [usrman on the subject](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-referencing-operator).